# Putting Code in with a Numbered List

Tags: support, markdown

I've noticed some interesting behavior with the numbered lists.

1. I have my first List Item
2. Second List Item

   This one includes a little more detail 
   Maybe a two line script
3. Last part of my List.

My code doesn't show up with the dark background, and it should be on two lines. Example:

```
This Example includes more detail with coding
Maybe a two line script
```

I've been able to get it to work with adding an extra line in, but it looks like that breaks the number sequence and rather than showing 3. It'll go back to 1.

1. I have my first List Item
2. Second List Item

```
This Example also includes more detail with coding 
Maybe a two line script
```

3. Last part of my list. <-- typed as a 3, but shows 1.

Is this by design? Is there any way we could continue a numbered list if we add code into the list?

Comment: If you need a real example and not "what if". I was going to add the numbered list to my question http://serverfault.com/questions/308781/webdav-system-error-67-in-windows-xp for the part of **Things That Haven't Worked**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Example
2. For good measure

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   main()
   {
       printf ("Hello World!\n");
   }
   ```
3. For Great Justice

   ```
   gosub AYBABTU
   ```

Where's the problem?

Comment: I guess that would be it then. Just need to have double the spaces to get it to hook into the number. Makes perfect sense. Thanks

Comment: @nix see http://serverfault.com/editing-help#advanced-lists

Comment: @Jeff outstanding. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff Jeebus, you wrote a book on it.